# I have an Error 429 with spotify api on single request

Tags: javascript, spotify, spotipy, libspotify, spotify-app

I am making a website that retrieves and displays my playlists, everything was working fine yesterday, this morning while I did not touch the code I have an error 429 every time I want to retrieve data on the api.

My code :

```
export const getUserPlaylist=async(params=null){
   params={
      params,
      headers:{'Authorization': `Bearer ${AccessToken}`}
   }
   const response=await axios.get("https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/playlists", params)
   return response.data
}
```

I've try with and without axios, that's not the problem.

I use this function in a React component class here :

```
async searchPlaylists(){
    if(!this.state.allPlaylists){
        const response=await getUserPlaylist({limit:50})
        this.setState({allPlaylists:response.items})
    }
    let playlists=[]
    for(let i of this.state.allPlaylists){
        if(i.name.indexOf(this.props.playlistName)===0){
            playlists.push(new Playlist(i))
            if(playlists.length===3) break
        }
    }
    this.setState({playlists})
}
async componentDidMount(){
    this.searchPlaylists()
}
async componentDidUpdate(){
    this.searchPlaylists()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`componentDidUpdate()` is a lifecycle hook which runs the code within it every time the component re-renders.
A component in React updates whenever there is a change in it's state or it's props.
`searchPlaylists()` sets the state, which causes a re-render.
In other words, you have created an infinite loop where you update the state at every re-render, which causes another re-render, sending an API request every time.

[For more in-depth information](https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-useeffect-infinite-loop/).

Comment: Thanks ! that's it, but now when my props change, my component do not change

Comment: You need to find a way around it, for instance, setting a condition in `componentDidUpdate()` so that `searchPlaylists()` gets called only whenever it's really needed, which depends on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Also, couple of extra notes: 1. You don't need `async` in functions without `await` statements (`componentDidMount()` & `componentDidUpdate()` in this case). 2. In `searchPlaylists()`, whenever your `if` condition is `true`, you essentially set the state twice in a row. Would highly recommend avoiding this. Setting the state is expensive and takes a toll on performance in the long run. Not to mention that it might create a race condition.

Comment: P.S. - you have other issues here. You are checking if `allPlaylists` is false, in which case you populate it in the state and immediately try to loop through it. This shouldn't work, since setting the state in React basically works like an asynchronous function, so when you try to loop through it, in most cases it should still be unpopulated. Also, you are effectively trampling the previous state every time you set it. Have a look at [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) as well.

Comment: I totally redid my component, in fact I had misunderstood the use of state, now everything works fine, thanks again for your help